# Which StackExchange to Ask my Question

Tags: discussion

I recently listened to a podcast about the Arpanet and how the Internet has evolved.

I do have some questions that I would like to discuss / questions to ask.

As the questions are technical in nature (it has to do with networking), is this the appropriate StackExchange to post my question?

Comment: Actually, questions about "_historical trivia that does not allow for a concise and non-subjective answer or is trivial/irrelevant to modern networking_" are off-topic on [Network Engineering](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/), but this is something that could be discussed in [chat]. Unfortunately, you don't seem to have enough reputation.

Comment: You may want to convert this to an answer, @RonMaupin, so the OP can accept it as an answer.

Comment: OK. I just did that.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, questions about "*historical trivia that does not allow for a concise and non-subjective answer or is trivial/irrelevant to modern networking*" are off-topic on [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/), but this is something that could be discussed in [Network Engineering Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11177). Unfortunately, you don't seem to have enough reputation to use chat.